# Find maximum of unsolvable integral with a parameter

Tags: numerical-integration, mathematical-optimization

Short description at the beginning.
I have a function of two variables:

```
dσ[x_, γ_] := ((-1 + γ)^2 +  4 x^4 γ^2 (1 + γ)^2 - 2 x^2 (-1 + γ (1 + 2 γ (2 + γ))))/(
x^3 (-1 + γ)^2 (1 + γ)^(3/2) Sqrt[1 - 2/x^2 + γ])
```

One can see (and also check with `FunctionDomain`) that this functin is real for `γ > 2/x^2 - 1`. And I need to integrate this with some Gaussian distribution:

```
f1[x_?NumericQ] := Block[{γav = 10^5, σ = 100}, NIntegrate[Exp[-(γ - γav)^2/(2 σ^2)]/(
Sqrt[2 π] σ) dσ[x, γ], {γ,2/x^2 - 1, γav + 20 σ}]]
```

Unfortunately, this integral can't be solved symbolically, so I make numeric integration. I've substituted for some values of `γ av` and `σ`. The lower limit of integral is because of restriction on `γ`, upper limit is arbitrary -- one can use 10, or 100 `σ`, `NIntegrate` can't deal with `∞`. Now I can plot this function vs. `x` and see this has peak near `x0 = Sqrt[2/(γav + 1)]`. My final goal is to build a function describing the dependence of this peak's distance form `x0` as function of `γ` and `σ`. So, I think I need some kind of interpolation for `f1[x]`.

I've tried `f2 = FunctionInterpolation[f1[x],{x, x0 - 10^-4, x0 + 10^-4}]`. This gives many warnings about `NIntegrate` and `FunctionInterpolation`, but the plot of interpolation is similar to the plot of `f1`. Then `FindMaximum[f2[x], {x, x0}]` gives strange messages about extrapolation -- starting value `x0` is inside of interpolation region and very near to maximum, why MMA goes outside region of interpolation?

`NMaximize` and `FindMaximum` on `f1[x]` gives many warnings about 'function has complex value near ...' and no output.

How to make robust procedure of finding maximum for arbitrary `γav` and `σ`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To overcome all these difficulties, there is a simple graphical solution:

```
dσ[x_, γ_] = ((-1 + γ)^2 + 4 x^4 γ^2 (1 + γ)^2 - 2 x^2 (-1 + γ (1 + 2 γ (2 +γ))))/(x^3 (-1 + γ)^2 (1 + γ)^(3/2) Sqrt[1 - 2/x^2 + γ]);
f1[x_?NumericQ] := Block[{γav = 1/2*10^5, σ = 50}, 
  NIntegrate[Exp[-(γ - γav)^2/(2 σ^2)]/(Sqrt[2 π] σ) dσ[x, γ], {γ,2/x^2 - 1, γav + 100 σ}]]

p = Plot[f1[x], {x, 0.0063, 0.0064}, PlotRange -> All, GridLines -> Automatic]//Quiet
```

[image]

```
pnt = First@Cases[Normal@p, Line[pt__] :> pt, ∞];
max = MaximalBy[pnt, Last]
```

{{0.00632692, 0.45993}}

A check with Table:

```
tab=ParallelTable[{x, f1[x]}, {x, 0.0063, 0.0064, 10^-7}];
MaximalBy[tab, Last]
```

{{0.0063269, 0.459927}}

```
ListLinePlot[tab, GridLines -> Automatic, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize@Medium, Point@max}]
```

[image]

"... why MMA goes outside region of interpolation?" , I don't know. Perhaps a developer can answer.

**Edit**

Because of your objection, I have recalculated the system with γav=1/2*10^5, σ=50. Where is the problem?

```
dσ[x_, γ_] = ((-1 + γ)^2 + 4 x^4 γ^2 (1 + γ)^2 - 2 x^2 (-1 + γ (1 + 2 γ (2 +γ))))/(x^3 (-1 + γ)^2 (1 + γ)^(3/2) Sqrt[1 - 2/x^2 + γ]);
f1[x_?NumericQ] := Block[{γav = 1/2*10^5, σ = 50}, 
  NIntegrate[Exp[-(γ - γav)^2/(2 σ^2)]/(Sqrt[2 π] σ) dσ[x, γ], {γ,2/x^2 - 1, γav + 20 σ}]]

p = Plot[f1[x], {x, 0.0063, 0.0064}, PlotRange -> All, GridLines -> Automatic] // Quiet
```

[image]

```
pnt = First@Cases[Normal@p, Line[pt__] :> pt, \[Infinity]];
max = MaximalBy[pnt, Last]
```

{{0.00632692, 0.45993}}

```
tab = Table[{x, f1[x]}, {x, 0.0063, 0.0064, 10^-7}];
MaximalBy[tab, Last]
```

{{0.0063269, 0.459927}}

```
ListLinePlot[tab, GridLines -> Automatic, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize@Medium, Point@max}]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for reply. But try use different values for `γav` and `σ`, say `γav = 0.5 10^5, σ = 50`. Plot method gives `{{0.00632688, 0.459918}}`. Table method `Table[{x, f1[x]}, {x, 0.006, 0.0065, 10^-7}]` with many warnings finally reads `{{0.0063269, 0.459927}}`. Table with smaller step `Table[{x, f1[x]}, {x, 0.006, 0.0065, 10^-8}]` takes too much time, and finally can't compute numerical integral and gives no answer. As I wrote I need some model for max vs. `γav, σ`, so I have to compute for many different values.

Comment: Continue comment. Plot and Table methods give not exactly same results. I read somewhere here in MSE, that such Plot method can be used as an estimation (Plot tries to show 'nice' picture, probably not too accurate in details of calculation of points). More accurate are `NMaximize` and the like, or `NDSolve` with original or interpolated function. We see, that Table (and interpolations as well) can not work for some parameters. That is the problem.

Comment: @Alx Sorry, please contact me if you found a successful method. This method provides a result, and thinks it is a graphical method, not an exact one! If you can plot your function, you can also determine the extremes. The error messages are generated during the calculation of your functions. They need a thorough examination.

Comment: concerning your Edit. I'm not sure if `20 σ` is enough in upper limit of integral. Strictly speaking, we should integrate up to infinity. So, if I change that `20 σ` to, say, `50 σ` I get odd messages from MMA: "... loss of precision ...", and "γ = 50000 + 50. σ is not a valid limit of integration". Why? This "Plot" method is good in the sense of it uses adaptive points' sampling and hence is faster than "Table" method, in which we have to set small enough step size for not to miss the peak. But if we think about infinity limit all goes slow and complicate.

Comment: @Alx It is not easy in life, but you can not expect anything. `NIntegrate` also reaches its limits at some point. Try some `Methods` and/or decrease the `Accuray` to 5. I have edited the first example in my answer with γav=1/2*10^5,σ=50 and γav+100 σ. I also used `ParallelTable`. With Mathematica 11.01 I have no problems. `Quiet` the warnings if they occur. This method yields at least a result; with `NMaximize` or `FindMaximum` you get nothing!

Comment: I slightly modified plot command: `x0 = Sqrt[2/(γav + 1)]` and then  `PlotRange -> {x, 0.95*x0, 1.05*x0}`. This is done for firther automatization in search of dependence of peaks' position on `γav`. For some `γav` and `σ` this +/- 5% interval probably is too wide, and I get warnings from NIntegrate. With your explicit interval I also have no problems. I have to think about how to choose automatic interval for Plot. In any case many thanks to you for answer and ideas, I accept your answer.